# How to get invoice_Id or invoice in Magento2 after order is placed using REST API

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api

After order is placed i am getting order_id and how can i get invoice of placed order (or) invoice_id after order is placed using Magento REST API.

Comment: does not find any api like this require. May you need to create custom API.SEE https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/

Comment: @Lavaraju Please check the answer, and let me know if you have any query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the searchCriteria to get all invoices for this placed order

Please try this endpoint

let us say that the order id  = 20

> Method = "GET"
>
> EndPoint = "/V1/invoices?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=order_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=20&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq"

Comment: @WISAM, please check once the following https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/247617/unable-to-place-order-in-magento2-2-6-using-rest-api

Answer (score 0):

> You can get invoice by using `invoice_id`

**REST API**

---

```
http://magento.host/rest/default/V1/invoices/{invoice_id}
```

- `method GET`
- `Authorization Bearer <admin token>`