# Unable to place order in Magento2.2.6 using REST API

Tags: rest-api, magento2.2.6, place-order

When we are working on Magento2.2.4 on the same, i got the proper response order_id was created.

But, coming to Magento2.2.6, i am getting the response like this[image]

We have checked the log files from var/log/exception.log

I got the following :

```
[2018-10-24 09:34:49] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'depoto.mg_sequence_order_1' doesn't exist, query was: INSERT INTO `mg_sequence_order_1` () VALUES () {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'depoto.mg_sequence_order_1' doesn't exist, query was: INSERT INTO `mg_sequence_order_1` () VALUES () at /home/depoto/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235, PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'depoto.mg_sequence_order_1' doesn't exist at /home/depoto/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228)"} []
[2018-10-24 09:35:05] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'depoto.mg_sequence_order_1' doesn't exist, query was: INSERT INTO `mg_sequence_order_1` () VALUES () {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'depoto.mg_sequence_order_1' doesn't exist, query was: INSERT INTO `mg_sequence_order_1` () VALUES () at /home/depoto/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235, PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'depoto.mg_sequence_order_1' doesn't exist at /home/depoto/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228)"} []
[2018-10-24 09:37:09] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'depoto.mg_sequence_order_1' doesn't exist, query was: INSERT INTO `mg_sequence_order_1` () VALUES () {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'depoto.mg_sequence_order_1' doesn't exist, query was: INSERT INTO `mg_sequence_order_1` () VALUES () at /home/depoto/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235, PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'depoto.mg_sequence_order_1' doesn't exist at /home/depoto/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228)"} []
```

We have the table `sequence_order_1`.

But the log file is showing the error with `depoto_mg_sequence_order_1`

Why this is happening like this?

Comment: Please check log files, there must be logs.

Comment: how can i check the logs could you please ??

Comment: See logs in var/log/exception.log.

Comment: You should run reindex and check again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the question, the existing table has name **`sequence_order_1`**, while the exception.log says, it is trying to find a table with name **`mg_sequence_order_1`** in the **`depoto`** database.

The problem seems to be that while installing Magento 2, table prefix was set as **`mg_`**.

While creating the table **`sequence_order_1`**, the prefix was not used, but the code written for getting the order information is using the table name by getTable() function.

So, Magento is adding the default prefix, i.e. **`mg_`** in the table name. That is why Magento is not able to get the table name and throwing the error that base table does not exist.

To fix the error, either drop the custom table (**sequence_order_1**), and recreate it with the prefix (**mg_**).

Or, if it is possible to change the code for getting the order info, you can pass the table name hardcoded (without using **getTable()** function).

I hope I was clear enough to solve your problem.